# Difference between make_pair and curly brackets { } for assigning a pair in C++?

Tags: c++, std-pair

I didn't find anyone answering this, is there any difference between the following :

```
v.push_back({x, y});
```

and :

```
v.push_back(make_pair(x, y));
```

Assuming that v was declared this way :

```
vector<pair<int,int> > v;
```

Comment: One way to find out is to look at the resulting assembly language

Comment: No, there isn't. The former is newer, post C++11 language feature. `std::make_pair` has been around for a long time.

Comment: The first creates (indirect) a temporary object which is passed to `push_back`. The other calls a function which creates the object which is returned and passed to the function. There might be more operations for the `make_pair` variant, but the end result (a pair containing `x` and `y` being pushed to the end of the vector) is still the same in both.

Comment: *Take in consideration that I'm asking for competitive programming usage* -- Explain exactly what this is supposed to mean, i.e. "competitive programming".  You either write solid, maintainable code or you don't.

Comment: No there are no difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's supposed to mean that I don't only care about the result, I care also about the complexity and memory usage... every detail counts even if it's small...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank your Sir , that's what I was looking for !

Comment: @NouemanKhalikine *I don't only care about the result, I care also about the complexity and memory usage* -- So solid programming doesn't care about complexity and memory usage??  What I see on this site when it comes to "competitive programming" is more often than not, the code looks like a mess and is disorganized, stupid `typedef` statements that obfuscate the code so that it is very hard to debug, just plain bad usage of C++, etc.  You can write code that is maintainable, easy to debug, efficient, etc. all without writing code in a haphazard and bad way.

Comment: Sigh. There are still people who are stuck in the 80s. See if you can find a relevant piece of code where `>> 1` has the same effect, yet is more efficient than `*2` on any relevant C++ compiler today. I'll wait.

Comment: @sehe `>>1` rarely has the same effect as `*2` — the former divides by 2, the latter multiplies by 2 :)

Comment: What was down vote for? I see no problem with this question. The 2nd form - older syntax triggers an extra copy-elision at compile-time on modern compilers. But the output binary is expected to be identical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried this in an online compiler, and as far as I can see the optimized assembly for make_pair is identical to {} syntax.

https://godbolt.org/z/P7Ugkt

Answer (score 14):

I think you might have accepted that answer a little too quickly.  The commonly accepted way to do this is like this:

```
vec.emplace_back (x, y);
```

And if you look at Godbolt, you can see that this inlines everything (which may or may not be what you want):

https://godbolt.org/z/aCl02d

Run it at Wandbox:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/uo3OqlS2X4s5YpB6

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int x = 1;
int y = 2;
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vec;

int main () {
    vec.push_back(std::make_pair(x, y));
    std::cout << "make_pair done\n";
    vec.push_back({x, y});
    std::cout << "push_back done\n";
    vec.emplace_back (x, y);
    std::cout << "emplace_back done\n";

    for (std::pair <int, int> p : vec)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
make_pair done
push_back done
emplace_back done
1, 2
1, 2
1, 2
```

Of course, everything runs faster if you reserve the appropriate number of elements in the vector up front.  Maybe *that's* what the people posing this question are really wanting you to say.

Comment: Yes, I know emplace_back faster than push_back, thanks a lot for pointing it out ;) It just was not part of my concern on this subject !

Answer (score 6):

`{x, y}` in `v.push_back({x, y})` is [aggregate initialization (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of `v`'s `value_type`, whereas `std::make_pair` is a function creating an `std::pair` with types deduced from its arguments.

One advantage of `push_back({x, y})` over `emplace_back(x, y)` is that you could keep small structures simple (without constructors) like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    // A(int _x, int _y) : x{_x}, y{_y} {}
};

int f()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.push_back({1, 2});
    // v.emplace_back(1, 2); // doesn't compile unless constructor is uncommented
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/5vzykh).