# map.insert({key, value}) How does this work?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair, keyvaluepair

I am a C programmer and new to C++.
I have used maps before and insertion often was like `map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value))`.
Today I saw in someone's code and further on [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-insert-in-c-stl/) a simpler syntax:

```
map.insert({key, value})
```

The linked website says `{k,v}` is a "pair" but does not explain how.
This would not have been a surprise in Javascript where braces denote objects and everything is dynamic. But when did C++ evolve to support such features.

I am looking for an explanation in terms of static typing and type coercion, how {k,v} is same as std::pair

**Edit**: This question has been marked as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236209/difference-between-make-pair-and-curly-brackets-for-assigning-a-pair-in-c) but the answers to that question deal entirely with what is faster by checking assembly code. The answer I was looking for has been given by user spectras in comments as list initialization. Before anyone rushes to mark a question as duplicate, do check whether answers to the linked question answer what was asked.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In particular you should pick a book that covers C++11 or higher as modern C++ is a different language (not really but it makes life so much better) than C++98/03

Comment: Sounds like you need a modern C++ book.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: I'm surprised, but I can't find any good question on basics of Uniform Initialization in C++. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720028/whats-the-difference-between-object-objargs-and-object-objargs?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be the closest to explaining the issue.

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236209/difference-between-make-pair-and-curly-brackets-for-assigning-a-pair-in-c) but the answers to that question deal entirely with what is faster by checking assembly code. The answer I was looking for has been given by user spectras above as list initialization. Before anyone rushes to mark a question as duplicate, do check whether answers to the linked question answer what was asked.